# Play midi files in google Colab notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, midi

I want to play a midi file with in the notebook, and I came across the following code:

```
from music21 import midi
def playMidi(path):
  mf = midi.MidiFile()
  mf.open(path) # path='abc.midi'
  mf.read()
  mf.close()
  s = midi.translate.midiFileToStream(mf)
  s.show('midi')
```

The code runs, but it doesn't do anything - any idea why?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The provided code reads a MIDI file and converts it to a music21 stream, but it doesn't actually play the audio. To play audio in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use the IPython.display.Audio class along with a MIDI player like FluidSynth to render the MIDI as audio.

First, install FluidSynth and a suitable soundfont. In Google Colab, you can do this by running the following commands:

```py
!apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qq libfluidsynth1 fluid-soundfont-gm
```

Then, install the `fluidsynth` Python package:

```py
!pip install fluidsynth
```

Now, use this updated playMidi function to play the MIDI file as audio in the notebook:

```py
import fluidsynth
from IPython.display import Audio
from music21 import converter

def playMidi(path):
    # Load MIDI file as a music21 stream
    s = converter.parse(path)

    # Set up FluidSynth MIDI player
    fl = fluidsynth.Synth()
    sfid = fl.sfload("/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2")
    fl.program_select(0, sfid, 0, 0)

    # Render the MIDI stream as audio
    audio_data = []
    for event in s.flat.notes:
        fl.noteon(0, event.pitch.midi, int(event.volume.velocity))
        audio_data.extend(fl.get_samples(int(event.duration.quarterLength * 44100)))
        fl.noteoff(0, event.pitch.midi)

    # Normalize audio data and play it in the notebook
    audio_data = np.array(audio_data, dtype="int16")
    audio_data = audio_data / (2**15 - 1)
    return Audio(audio_data, rate=44100)
```

Now, when you call `playMidi("path/to/your/midi/file.mid")`, it should play the audio in the notebook. Replace `"path/to/your/midi/file.mid"` with the path to the MIDI file you want to play.

Comment: Executing the first apt-get line in Colab returns `E: Package 'libfluidsynth1' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Also for the Python part: `AttributeError: module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute 'Synth'`